# copy contents of one table to another table in django

Tags: python, django

How do I copy all the rows in a django table to a new table while retaining the old table contents?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=sql+select+into

Answer (score 3):

Execute [raw SQL directly](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

```
from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()
# commit required
cursor.execute("SELECT * INTO %s FROM %s" % (newtable, oldtable))
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

Working from model objects, the table name will be stored in `_meta.db_table`